# What does it mean to put $\sqrt{\phantom{-v}}$ alone below a square rooted expression?

Tags: radicals

In Yaremenko's paper [here](https://globaljournals.org/GJSFR_Volume17/2-Electromagnetic-theory-from-standpoint.pdf), on the 5th page of the pdf, which is page ten, in section IV, he uses a square root symbol alone under $\sqrt{-g}$ and $\sqrt {-g} \, dV$.  What does this mean?

Comment: The symbol has stronger lines and seems to extend into empty space without extending the line height. I suppose this is an artefact.

Comment: Looks like an error to me.

Comment: seems like a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both underset, empty radicals are typos.  If they were not typos a third one would appear in the last display of the cited page attached to the last term in the parentheses.  There it isn't.  Ignore them.